# How can I make a 3D Bode plot of a function?

Tags: plotting, functions, function-construction

I'm trying to do a Bode plot in 3D for the function below, but there is no built-in function for that.

How can I do that? It would also be nice if you could use a mesh to make it easier to see.

```
tf = s^2/(s^2 + 2 s + 5)
```

The shape of the plot may not be same as in the image, but it is a 3D object like that.

In a 2D Bode plot, `s` is replaced with `i*w` and then the magnitude/modulus of the function with frequency `w` is plotted. However, in a 3D plot you replace `s` with `σ + i*w` and plot the magnitude of the function with a different `σ` and `w`.

```
tf = s^2/(s^2 + 2 s + 5);
mag = Abs[ComplexExpand[tf /. s -> \[Sigma] + I*w]];
Plot3D[mag, {\[Sigma], -1000, 1000}, {w, -100, 100}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {None, None, "Log"}]
```

[image]

Comment: what is a Bode plot, mathematically? the wikipedia article is a bit hard to parse for someone without the EE background. (hopefully someone who already knows comes along, but in the event they don't...)

Comment: In 2D bode plot, they replace `s` with `i*w` and then plot the magnitude/modulus of the function with frequency `w`. However, in 3D plot you should replace `s` with `σ + i*w` and plot the maginitude of the function with different `σ` and `w`.

Comment: Like this?: `ComplexPlot3D[tf, {s, -2 - 3 I, 0 + 3 I}, 
 AxesLabel -> {\[Sigma], I*\[Omega]}, BoxRatios -> {2, 3, 1}]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 that is nice. Adding mesh may be easier to see though. How can I make a bold red curve in the intersection of the graph and the plane forming by `σ = 0` and `w`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May be like this.

```
tf = s^2/(s^2 + 2 s + 5);
mag = Abs[ComplexExpand[tf /. s -> σ + I*w]];
SetOptions[Plot3D, BoundaryStyle -> None, PlotRange -> {0, 8}, 
  ViewPoint -> {2.54, 1.27, 1.8}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
  ClippingStyle -> Yellow];
fig1 = Plot3D[mag, {σ, -2, 0}, {w, -3, 3}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
   MeshShading -> {Yellow, Pink, Brown, Gray, Blue, Orange, Purple, 
     Cyan}, Mesh -> {20, 20, 8}];
fig2 = Plot3D[mag, {σ, -2, 1}, {w, -3, 3}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &}, MeshShading -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> None, Mesh -> {20, 20}];
fig3 = Plot3D[mag, {σ, -2, 1}, {w, -3, 3}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {#1 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, PlotStyle -> None, 
   MeshStyle -> {Thick, Red}];
Show[fig1, fig2, fig3]
```

[image]

Comment: the plot is very nice

Answer (score 6):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

tf = s^2/(s^2 + 2 s + 5);

Manipulate[
 Show[
  ComplexPlot3D[tf,
   {s, -2 - 3 I, 1/4 + 3 I},
   MeshFunctions -> mf,
   MeshStyle -> {Black, Darker[Green]},
   Mesh -> 9,
   PlotPoints -> 50,
   MaxRecursion -> 5,
   PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic,
     LegendLabel -> HoldForm[Arg[tf]]],
   PlotRange -> {0, 10}],
  ComplexPlot3D[tf,
   {s, -2 - 3 I, 1 + 3 I},
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[0],
   MeshFunctions -> {Re[#1] &},
   Mesh -> {{0.}},
   MeshStyle -> {{Red, Thick}}],
  AxesLabel ->
   (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {σ, ω, 
      "|tf|"}),
  BoxRatios -> {2, 3, 1},
  SphericalRegion -> True,
  ImagePadding -> 30],
 {{mf, {Abs[#2] & , Arg[#2 ] & }, "MeshFunctions"},
  {{Abs[#2] & , Arg[#2 ] & } -> {"|tf|", "arg(tf)"},
   {Re[#2] &, Im[#2] &} -> {"Re(tf)", "Im(tf)"},
   {Re[#1] &, Im[#1] &} -> {"Re(s)", "Im(s)"}}, 
  ControlType -> PopupMenu}]
```

[image]